# Is there a way using non continuous ip and path for minio server pool and cluster

Tags: minio

I need make a minio cluster on servers which are in use, so I can't change ip or mount pointon of those servers.

So, I can't use this "http://host{o...z}/export{1...m}" syntax, for IPs and PATHs are not continuous.

I know that for single server pool, minio can accept non continuous IP and PATH, like this:

> ./minio server http://x.x.x.182:/data1 http://x.x.x.184:/data3 http://x.x.x.186:/data5 http://x.x.x.188:/data7

Is there a way to bend the rule for cluster? Or maybe a fork that accept non continuous IP and PATH.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand MinIO server using pools you can run the command like

```
minio server 
http://minio{1...4}.example.net:9000/mnt/disk{1...4}/minio http://minio{5...12}.example.net:9000/mnt/disk{1...8}/minio
```

Here the MinIO server hosts with sequential hostnames  which can be mapped to non-continuous  ip using the `etc/hosts` file.
You can configure not continuous ip address to continuous host names and use the pools.

The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.

Comment: In order to use non sequential Ip , I actually did some change in code. Well in the end, It turns out minio just not fit in my situation. Thanks Anyway.